# How to get random row in linqtosql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

i want to take a random row from database by using linqtosql, but my requirement is some different....

my code is this...

```
var qry = from tb in DC.tbcategory
          where tb.parentID == null
          order by tb.sortOrder
          select new
          {
                categoryID = tb.CategoryID,
                ImageID = (from tb in DC.tbImage
                          where tb.CategoryID == tc.CategoryID
                          orderby Guid.NewID()
                          select tb.ImageID).FirstorDefault()
          }
```

in this example tbcategory and tbimage has one to many relation and i want to take random record of tbImage table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Create a view in SQL server for take a random record

```
CREATE VIEW RandomView
AS
SELECT NEWID() As ID
```

Then create a functin in SQL server

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNewId
(
)
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT ID FROM RandomView)
END
```

then use you linq query like this

```
var qry = from tb in DC.tbcategory
          where tb.parentID == null
          order by tb.sortOrder
          select new
          {
                categoryID = tb.CategoryID,
                ImageID = (from tb in DC.tbImage
                          where tb.CategoryID == tc.CategoryID
                          orderby DC.GetNewId()
                          select tb.ImageID).FirstorDefault()
          }
```

I hope it will work definitely....

Comment: Why do you need a view?  You can just call `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use this extension method on your resultset. Here's the [URL](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=350).

Comment: He should run on the server, not the client.

Comment: Why is that if I may ask?   

@topic, here's how you could do it using extension methods in stead of regular linq-syntax:

`code` var qry = DC.tbcategory.Where(tb => tb.ParentID == null).OrderBy(tb => tb.sortOrder).SelectRandom();